# Почему для одного и того же класса пришлось создать другое правило?

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток! Есть код: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6y9f4mwv/)

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 940px; 
  padding: 0 10px; 
}


/* Header */
.header {
  height: 800px;
  text-align: center; 
  background: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/innovation-cloud/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
  background-size: cover;
}

.header .container {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
}

.header h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 100px; 
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media (min-width:850px) {
  .header h1 {
    font-size: 120px;
  }
}

.header p {
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header .btn {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 10px 40px; 
  transition: background .5s;  
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #117bff;
  cursor: pointer; 
  transition: background .5s;  
}


/* Nav */
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center; 
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -40px;
}

.nav .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff; 
  padding: 30px 10px 31px 10px;
  transition: background .5s;
}

.nav {
  background-color: #000;
}

/* Main */
.main .container {
  margin: 80px auto;
}

.main .container img {
  width: 196px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}


/* Jumbotron */
.jumbotron {
  height: 600px; 
  text-align: right;
  background: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/innovation-cloud/jumbotron_bg.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
  background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  top: 220px;
}

.jumbotron h2 {
  color: #fff;
}

.jumbotron p {
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.jumbotron .btn {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background .5s;
}

.jumbotron .btn:hover {
  transition: background .5s;
  background: #117bff;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>
      Innovation cloud
    </h1>
    <p>
      Connect your ideas globally
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Learn More</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li class="btn">Register</li>
      <li class="btn">Schedule</li>
      <li class="btn">Sponsors</li>
      <li class="btn">About</li>
      <li class="btn">Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/innovation-cloud/cloud.svg" />
    <h2>The Innovation Cloud Conference</h2>
    <p>Connect with the best minds across a wide range of industries to share ideas and brainstorm new solutions to challenging problems.</p>
    <p>Hear industry leaders talk about what worked (and what didn't) so that you can save time on your most challenging projects.</p>
    <p>Learn about the latest research and technologies that you can use immediately to invent the future.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>
      Stay Connected
    </h2>
    <p>
      Receive weekly insights from industry insiders.
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Join</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Прошу обратить внимание на элементы HTML-кода с классом `btn` в секциях `Header`, `Nav` и `Jumbotron`.

Для кнопок в `header` и `nav` правило `.btn:hover` работает отлично (при наведении мыши кнопки загораются), а для кнопки в секции `jumbotron` – нет. Для `jumbotron` пришлось писать отдельное правило – `.jumbotron .btn:hover`.

Почему общее для всех кнопок правило `.btn:hover` не подействовало на кнопку в `jumbotron`?

Comment: потому, что правило `.jumbotron .btn` по весу больше, чем `.btn:hover` и лежит ниже в списке стилей. потому и перебивает

Comment: @lexxl, я не об этом. Изначально правила `.jumbotron .btn` не было. Я его дописал, т.к. правило `.btn:hover` не работало для кнопки, которая располагается в секции `jumbotron`. Вот я и спрашиваю - почему `.btn:hover` не работал для этой кнопки?

Comment: уточню: я про `.jumbotron .btn`, а не про `.jumbotron .btn:hover`

Comment: @lexxl , извиняюсь - не внимательно просмотрел. Хорошо, тогда почему `.nav .btn` отлично принимает правило `.btn:hover` хоть и имеет селектор схожий с `.jumbotron .btn` и лежит ниже `.btn:hover`, как и `.jumbotron .btn`?

Comment: `.nav .btn` не задаёт свойство `background` (`background-color`), потому в данном случае не имеет влияния

Comment: @lexxl, понял. Спасибо за разъяснение!

Comment: @lexxl, и еще. Как эта приоритезация правил называется? Где про нее можно прочитать?

Comment: Нашел. Calculating a selector's specificity [https://habrahabr.ru/post/137588/]

Comment: Оформил в виде ответа. И да, статья на хабре должна помочь разобраться в этом вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое поведение обусловлено основной спецификой работы каскадных стилей (CSS).
В данном случае правило `.jumbotron .btn` по весу больше, чем `.btn:hover` и лежит ниже в списке стилей, поэтому перебивает значение для `background` своим значением.
Чтобы перебить влияние свойств `.jumbotron .btn`, приходится вводить селектор `.jumbotron .btn:hover`.
А, например, в случае для `.nav .btn` фон кнопки при наведении изменяется, т.к. данное правило не содержит свойства `background-color` и, как следствие, не имеет влияние.

Рекомендую почитать небольшую статью, где эти моменты кратко и доступно описаны: [Каскадирование](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/kaskadirovanie)